# Line element to matrix form

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Suppose I have a metric described by a line element for points on its corresponding manifold. Is there a method for converting that given line element to matrix form?

Comment: Do you understand that the coefficient of $dt^2$ is $g_{tt}$, etc.?

Comment: If your line element is in a form that makes it a hassle to expand out the factors use a code like [this](https://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=1042#p1042)

Answer (score 1):

Just expand it out. $$g_{\mu\nu}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 g_{tt} & g_{tx} & g_{ty} & g_{tz} \\
 g_{xt} & g_{xx} & g_{xy} & g_{xz} \\
 g_{yt} & g_{yx} & g_{yy} & g_{yz} \\
 g_{zt} & g_{zx} & g_{zy} & g_{zz} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ $$dx^\mu = \left(dt,dx,dy,dz\right)$$ So then take the line element $$ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$$ and since $g_{\mu \nu}$ is symmetric we get $$ds^2=g_{tt}\ dt^2+2\ g_{tx}\ dt\ dx + 2\ g_{ty} \ dt \ dy + ... + g_{xx} \ dx^2 + 2 \ g_{xy} \ dx \ dy+ ... + g_{zz} \ dz^2$$ Which you can solve component-wise by inspection to get the coefficients of the metric tensor from the line element.